# change email of every wordpress user subscribed to a bbpress forum

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bbpress

I want to do a test mailing in my staging area, to see if a new WP plugin works for BBpress. 
In order to do this, i want to change all emails to my personal email address for all that are subscribed to the forum (so i don't accidentally send out mails to real users).
The problem is that the WP user email is found in the DB wp_users and the forum meta info is found in the DB wp_usermeta.
What SQL statement would i use if i wanted to change the email of all bbpress "Participants" to "myemail@email.com".
I want to do something like:

```
UPDATE wp_users SET user_email = "myemail@email.com" WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = "participant";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from a collegue, this is the solution:

```
    update wp_users  
    set wp_users.user_email = "myemail@email.com"
    where
    wp_users.ID IN (
    select  
    wp_usermeta.user_id
    from wp_usermeta
    where (wp_usermeta.meta_key = "wp_capabilities") &&  (wp_usermeta.meta_value like 
    "%bbp_participant%")   
    )
    ;
```